# Matching a sequence of non-empty, delimited strings with a Regular Expression

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm not an expert with Regular Expressions, and I'm having serious problems matching a particular pattern.

The pattern is:

*A sequence of consecutive, arbitrary words marked with a prefix and a suffix. Inside the word there should be at least one character*.

I mean, suppose that the prefix is "AB" and the suffix is "YZ". With this input:

```
AB----YZAB====YZABYZ//AB++YZ,,,AB====YZAB---YZ
```

The matched groups should be:

AB----YZAB====YZ , AB++YZ , AB====YZAB---YZ

The group ABYZ should not be matched, because it is "empty" (there is nothing between the prefix and the suffix.

I tried with

```
(AB(.*?)YZ)+
```

But the ABYZ is detected as part of the sequence, as the "*" may match nothing. If I force to use non-empty groups with

```
(AB(.+?)YZ)+
```

But still no lock, it detects groups

AB----YZAB_____YZABYZ//AB++YZ and AB====YZAB---YZ

I tried many other, more complex, regExps, with no luck.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:AB(?:(?!AB).)+?YZ)+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XUIDru/1).

**Details**

- `(?:AB(?:(?!AB).)+?YZ)+` - one or more repetitions of

  - `AB` - an `AB` substring
  - `(?:(?!AB).)+?` (or `(?:(?!AB|YZ).)+`) - any char but a line break char, 1 or more repetitions, as few as possible, that does not start an `AB` char sequence (a so-called [*tempered greedy token*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970))
  - `YZ` - a `YZ` substring.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much for your help, and for the reference to the tempered greedy token explanation.